# HTTP POST with file attachment

Tags: php, http

I am trying to receive orders from a supplier using HTTP delivery.  They were unsure what is being sent so i have set a general capture to see what is happening.  Here is my code:

```
<?
$handle = fopen("landstore.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']));
$data = array("headers" => headers_list(), "post" => $_POST, "get" => $_GET, "file" => $_FILES);
file_put_contents($handle, json_encode($data));

if (!empty($_POST)) {
fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "Post ON"); 
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." post =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
        }
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
if (!empty($_FILES))    {
fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "Files ON");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." file =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
    }
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

if (isset($_GET))   {   
fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "Get ON");
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." get =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

The response is this:

```
POST2015-04-01 11:58:13Get ON outFileName get =/exnfs/UAT2/requests/001152/11525750/Dispatch/SIMULATED_OUTPUT_N150324_001_31_R_HCP_60.pdf.xml,
```

I asked the supplier if the link "/exnfs/UAT2/..." was what i should be using to retreive the xml file, in whihc case i would need a prefix.  They say that i should ignore the link as this is there for validation purposes and that there should be an xml file attached to the post.

According to the response, the request method is post, but there are no entries being given for $_POST in the foreach loop and the path is being returned as a $_GET and there are no $_FILES.

Can somebody help me to interpret the response please.  Is it possible that there is a file there somewhere as well as the path being sent by post/get(? not sure which?) and how would i retreive the file if it exists.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you use "multipart/form-data" in you form with files?

Comment: Hi Alexey - thank for the answer.  There is no form as such.  I order some electronic products by sending an XML file to the customer.  It is done using cURL.  The supplier can offer email delivery or http delivery.  When you include the option for http delivery, you get the post to the URL that you have told them to register for your account.  Their server sends the message/files/whatever it is to my php files shown above.  They say that it has an xml file attached, but i cannot see any file with $_FILES - could it be hiding in a get/post or put and how would i know?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry i order from the supplier not the customer $%:@/!  not thinking while typing....

Comment: Anyway when data comes to PHP it's must be a multipart or PHP doesn't see any files at all. I use almost the same in my android application so I prepare complete form-like answer like browser do.